# Can you can row count after using wpdb get_var?

Tags: wordpress

I understand that $wpdb->get_var returns a single value.  But is there way to determine the number of rows that the query matched?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$wpdb->num_rows might work. I'm sure it works for $wpdb->get_row but not sure about $wpdb->get_var. Try it & let us know. :)

Comment: it does not work - Fatal error: Call to undefined method wpdb::num_rows()

Comment: Radi, can you provide the statement that triggers the error? if you literally wrote `$wpdb->num_rows()` then it wouldn't work because `num_rows` is a property, not a method, so try it without `()` like $wpdb->num_rows